# Toggle DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED Android

Tags: android, development-environment

this is what I'm trying to do

```
Settings.Global.putInt(my_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 1);
```

but it's not working. My app is a system/app and has WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission.

Thanks a lot

EDIT: For example, this code below is working fine:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(my_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

**To enable developer settings:**

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(my_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 1);
Settings.Global.putInt(my_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 1);
```

**To disable developer settings:**

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(my_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0);
Settings.Global.putInt(my_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
```